# hadith about the dajjal

Tags: hadith, prophet-muhammad, authenticity, dajjal

> Jabir bin Abdullah (ra) narrated that Prophet (saw) while discussing
>   about Dajjal said: And his donkey on which he will arrive, will have a
>   span of 40 hands between his two ears. [Musnad Ahmad]

I want to know if this hadith is authentic or not (weak or fabricated etc.) ?

and

Is Musnad Ahmed an authentic source of hadiths as I heard that it contains many weak hadiths and has problems but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1):

The chain of narrators goes as follows:

> `Muhammad bin Sabiq` *told us:* that `Ibrahim bin Tahman` *told us:* *from* `Abu Al-Zubair` ***from*** `Jabir bin Abdullah`

Both Bukhari and Muslim have accepted hadiths from these narrators.

There is, however, one problem with `Abu Al-Zubair`. He would do *tadlees*. If such a narrator does not explicitly state that he has heard directly from the narrator above him his hadith is considered relatively weak. In this hadith, he has done the same and used the word عن (i.e. from) while reporting. This word creates the possibility that he has not actually heard it from `Jabir bin Abdullah` directly and is hiding the intermediate weak narrator.